# Tracing Family Tree lineage for Romanian ancestor?

Tags: romania

His mother’s maiden name listed on his Canadian marriage license was Mary Loshonsko, Bukovina,Roumania.

He and his brother Thomas were gotten out of Romania around 1905 - 1910.

They were not able to speak English and for that reasons the forms at arrival, etc. were filled out wrong.

Also because their calendar year was different he only made a guess at his birth day. He knew it was Easter Sunday at times.

He went by the name Nicholas Nester Cashol and he was about 14years old.. Birthday. April 17,1896. His brother Thomas and him traveled together. Thomas was a couple years older.

---

The only information I have the names I listed.

My Grandfather:  Nicholas Nester Cashol.  Spelling is incorrect because of the pronunciation of his words.
His brother:  Gregory Cashol.He was 2 years older. 
His mother:   Mary Loshenska.
His father:   Thomas Cashol.
Where he lived:  Raronche, Bukovina, Romania.
I estimated his birth to be April 17, 1897.  He was born close to Easter. I was told that their calendar year was different than others. He celebrated Christmas on January 6. Our little Christmas. 
I don't where he sailed from or port he arrived at. Nicholas stayed in New Brunswick and married and raised his family.  Gregory went to Western Canada and then back home to fight in the war.
I have a picture of his family in a tragically fancy dress

I am looking for correct spelling for his last name, birth record, church records. Family members.
I am looking for information as to where to search for this information.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than simply asking for any information.  Are you perhaps seeking a birth record for Nicholas?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Please tell us more about what sources you already have, and what you are trying to learn.  I don't know what forms you mean when you say 'at arrival'.  If you mean a passenger list, those were created at the port where the passengers departed from Europe -- at the offices of the steamship company. If you have a passenger list, who purchased the ticket?

Answer (score 3):

This response doesn't have many definitive answers for you, but it includes some record findings, and identifies gaps and inconsistencies in the data presented above.

**Arrival in Canada**
Nicholas arrived in 1913, according to the 1921 Canada census. This is later than your estimate, but it makes more sense that Nicholas and Gregory were older, if they were unaccompanied on the voyage. I couldn't find the passenger list for either brother, but my search criteria were based on the provided details. Likely, they arrived in Saint John NB, but that assumption is based primarily on Nicholas' continuing residence in New Brunswick.

**Citizenship**
In 1921, he was a Romanian citizen, but Romania was only awarded Bukowina after World War 1. Nicholas was probably had been an Austrian citizen and may have applied for new identity papers from the Romanian government (because of his ethnicity). If he was already planning to become a Canadian citizen, he may have skipped this. However, he doesn't seem to have become a Canadian citizen before 1946.

**Religion and calendars**
Austria had switched to the Gregorian calendar in 1582, with the rest of Catholic Europe. Bukowina became one of its crownlands in 1774. However, various religious communities adjusted their church year so as to not loose the 12 days of the conversion. [Greek Catholics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_Greek_Catholic_Church) (Nicholas' religion per the 1921 census) celebrate Christmas on 6 January, but it's not clear which calendar governs how Easter is calculated. Easter can occur over a wide span of dates.

**Birthplace**
"Raronche, Bukovina, Romania" seems to be [Rarancze](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&placeId=1122022&query=%2Bplace%3A%22Austria%2C%20Bukowina%2C%20Rarancze%22&subjectsOpen=1122021-50,1122099-50) (Bukowina) aka Rarancea (Cernăuţi) and now [Ridkivtsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridkivtsi) (Ukrainian: Рідківці; Romanian: Rarancea), in Novoselytsia Raion, Chernivtsi Oblast, Ukraine. Although Nicholas' birthplace was in [Greater Romania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Romania) in 1921, the northern part of Bukowina, became part of Ukraine after 1945. FamilySearch has [Rarancze Orthodox Church metrical books, 1881-1938](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/1388597?availability=Family%20History%20Library), but no mention of Greek Catholic records (if separate). A gazetter of Bukowina may help in identifying the Greek Catholic parishes near Nicholas' birthplace.

**Surname spelling**
Emigrants were supposed to carry identity documentation. Passenger lists were constructed referencing those documents and officials at both departure and arrival ports had access to translators; language should not have been an issue. If the brothers had been from the Russian empire, the Cyrillic alphabet would have complicated how the surname was anglicized. But the Austrian empire used the Latin alphabet. (Interestingly, the description for the Orthodox metrical books referenced above includes "Text in Romanian in old Cyrillic script before 1875 and in Roman script thereafter").

**Gregory Cashol**
I could not find Gregory in Canadian WW1 military records. Did he return to fight for Austria? You said there was a photo of his family; are you in contact with them? Since he was older, they may have information that would be helpful.

---

**Records**
[1921 Census of Canada](https://search.ancestry.ca/cgi-bin/sse.dll?db=CanCen1921&indiv=try&h=8678407)
"Nick Cachal", single, age 28, born Roumania, parents born Roumania, arrived 1913, citizenship Roumania, ethnicity Roumania, religion Greek Catholic

[New Brunswick Provincial Marriages 1789-1950](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QVBF-1V55)
Nicholas Cashol & Mary Veronica Ryan, 1927 Norton NB
Nicholas' fields name parents, born Romania, age 31, religion R.C.

[Findagrave memorial](http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=129979201)
Nickolas N. Cashol, 1896-1963
Norton Sacred Heart Cemetery, Norton NB
[Veronica M. Cashol, 1908-1965, 129979207]

[Search: Naturalization Records by name, 1915-1946](http://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/discover/immigration/citizenship-naturalization-records/naturalized-records-1915-1951/Pages/search-naturalization-1915-1939.aspx)
Nicholas Cashol not found

[Personnel Records of the First World War](http://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/discover/military-heritage/first-world-war/personnel-records/Pages/personnel-records.aspx)
Gregory Cashol not found